# Socat interacting with specific host (reverse shell) from mutiple clients/connections

Tags: linux, netcat, socat

I have a threaded c/c++ application that gives a pty reverse shell installed on multiple linux clients they all connect back to same server/port
now I need to find a reliable method to interact with a specific host so I can for example bash script/alias it later.

by using socat I think it should be like keep listening and wait for a specific host to select and fork and interact with it's shell and close/exit if it's not that specific host, I thought something like that would work

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork SYSTEM:'[ $(hostname) != "host.d.com" ] && { exit;}',pty,stderr
```

but it doesn't give me any output, I tried with a simple command like

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork SYSTEM:'/usr/bin/id',pty,stderr
```

and I get this error every time a client connects

`socat[1567] E write(5, 0x7faa9c802c00, 341): Input/output error`

keep in mind that I get the usual shell waiting for input with this command thats working fine for the first client that connects in

```
socat - TCP-LISTEN:8080
```

I tried also with nmap's ncat --allow option `ncat -lvvp 8080 --keep-open --max-conns 1 --allow some ip/host` but unfortunately I can't use it cause hosts are nated under same IP

So is there any solution to this problem that would allow me to manage/select/interact with multiple reverse client shells without having to use diffrent port for each client also I'm keeping it plain for testing but I need it to work over SSL thats why I'm trying with socat and ncat

I've seen some python projects on github but they are all buggy and weak